# How to combine results of two select, UNION All, rand()

Tags: sql, select, random, union, sql-limit

There is table, which contains some answers. One of answers is true (field tf=1), and several are false (field tf=0).
How to select 1 true answer and N false random answers? The result must be in random order.
This is my example, it works, but true answer always in first row:

```
(SELECT * FROM answers where tf=1 and `questionsid`=1 limit 1)
UNION all
(SELECT * FROM answers where tf=0 and `questionsid`=1 order by rand() limit 5 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. By the way, I have another solution, which also works:

```
(SELECT *, rand() as t FROM answers where tf=1 and `questionsid`=1 limit 1)
UNION all
(SELECT *, rand() as t FROM answers where tf=0 and `questionsid`=1 order by rand() limit 5 )
order by t
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample data this is untested however presumably you can wrap your query with an outer `select`, so after selecting the one right answer and 5 additional random wrong answers, return all 6 again ordered randomly:

```
select * from (
    (select * 
    from answers 
    where tf=1 and questionsid=1 
    limit 1)
    union all
    (select * 
    from answers 
    where tf=0 and questionsid=1 
    order by Rand() 
    limit 5)
)r
order by rand()
```

Comment: Thank You for answer. But returns error:

#1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @Lookhome It seems the brackets around the subqueries are required by MySql (I am guessing from your syntax this is your database, you have not indicated in your question), I have edited the answer above it should work now, see [this test Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04d3ae2c12115e55b9c1aff888bdfcc8)